# Re-write of split function not able to free memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

`Currently have this code. It follows a specific set of guidelines necessary; hence, no while loops or other functions that aren't created by ourselves in the header file.

I am writing a function that will split a string. Only External functs. allowed are malloc and free. Basically it allocates (with malloc(3)) and returns an array of strings obtained by splitting ’s’ using the character ’c’ as a delimiter. The array must end with a NULL pointer.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libft.h"

static int ft_length(char const *s, char c)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t words;

    i = 0;
    words = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
       while (s[i] == c)
       {
            i++;
       }
        if (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0')
        {
            words++;
        }
        while (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return (words);
}

char    *ft_copy(char *s, char c)
{
    int     i;
    char    *cpy;

    i = 0;
    while (*s && *s == c)
        s++;
    while (s[i] && s[i] != c)
        i++;
    cpy = malloc(sizeof(char) * i + 1);
    if (cpy == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (s[i] && s[i] != c)
    {
        cpy[i] = s[i];
        i++;
    }
    cpy[i] = '\0';
    return (cpy);
}

static void *cleanup(char **cpy, int j)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < j)
    {
        free(cpy[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

char **ft_split(char const *s, char c)
{
    size_t  i;
    char    **cpy;
    size_t  count;
    size_t  j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    if (!s && !c)
        return (NULL);
    count = ft_length(s, c);
    cpy = malloc(sizeof(char *) *(count + 1));
    if (!cpy)
        return (NULL);
    while (s[i])
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if ((int)i == ft_strlen((char *)s) && j == 0)
        {
            cpy[0] = 0;
            return (cpy);
        }
        if (s[i] != c)
        {
            cpy[j] = ft_copy((char *)&(s[i]), c);
            if (cpy[j] == NULL)
            {
                cleanup(cpy, j);
                return (NULL);
            }
            j++;
        }
        while (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0')
            i++;
    }
    cpy[count] = NULL;
    return (cpy);
}
```

However, when running a tester about 1 byte of memory is not properly freed as seen in these lines:

```
Error in test 3: ft_split("hello!zzzzzzzz", 122:'z'):
Memory leak: 0x55ae6a0998f0 - 1 bytes
You failed to free the memory allocated at:
ft_copy's malloc allocaton:
Error in test 4: ft_split("\\t\\t\\t\\thello!\\t\\t\\t\\t", 9:'\\t'):
Memory leak: 0x55ae6a09a920 - 1 bytes
You failed to free the memory allocated at:
ft_copy's malloc allocaton:
Error in test 7: ft_split("^^^1^^2a,^^^^3^^^^--h^^^^", 94:'^'):
Memory leak: 0x55ae6a09aa00 - 1 bytes
You failed to free the memory allocated at:
ft_copy's malloc allocaton:
```

Wondering if a complete new rewrite for the code would be needed? However I seem to be very close just do not know where this single byte that I can't release is coming from.

I expect all memories to be properly freed.

Comment: I think `cleanup` is missing `free(cpy);`

Comment: ... in cleanup.  But that would be a a `sizeof(char **)` leak (i.e. 8 bytes on amd64).

Comment: Please edit your question to ensure it contains a [mre] (i.e. a program with a `main()` that demonstrate the issue).

Comment: Prefer `for` loops when you increment stuff.  No need for `()` when you return stuff.  Avoid casts it's often a signal that you have the wrong type.  `cpu[j] == NULL` probably works but technically incorrect you want to use '\0'.  Minimize the use of declaring variables separately from initialization; minimize scope of variables whenever possible and avoid reusing the same variable for different things.

Comment: In `static void * cleanup()` you `return (0)` but it should be a NULL.  You use `int` for some indices and others `size_t`.  I prefer the unsigned type (like `size_t`) when the index is non-negative.

Comment: In the successful case ft_split returns a non-NULL `char **` but `cleanup()` requires a count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `cleanup()` should free `cpy`.
2. `cleanup()` requires a count `j` but in the normal case you don't have the count so eliminate the argument and rely on the `NULL` instead.
3. `ft_strlen()` missing so eliminated it. You call `ft_strlen()` every iteration of the outer loop to figure out if we are at the end of the string.  You can do that by simply checking for `s[i] == '\0'` or `!s[i]`.
4. Minimize scope of variables.
5. Prefer initialized variables.
6. Prefer `for()` to `while()` when iterating over arrays.
7. (Not fixed) Don't reuse variables for different things.  This may or may not be a dependency.  See minimize scope of variables.
8. `NULL` vs `\0` vs `0`.
9. (Partial fixed) Prefer using an unsigned types for non-negative variables (`size_t`).
10. `(char *)&(s[i])` is fine but `s + i` is a more direct way of saying that.
11. `if ((int)i == ft_strlen((char *)s) && j == 0)` means we are done with the string so just break to avoid duplicate code.
12. `if (s[i] != c)` is redundant.  You know the it's the case otherwise previous loop would not have terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int ft_length(char const *s, char c) {
    size_t words = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; s[i];) {
        for(; s[i] == c; i++);
        if (s[i] != c && s[i])
            words++;
        for(; s[i] != c && s[i]; i++);
    }
    return words;
}

char *ft_copy(const char *s, char c) {
    for(; *s && *s == c; s++);
    int i = 0;
    for(; s[i] && s[i] != c; i++);
    char *cpy = malloc(i + 1);
    if (!cpy)
        return NULL;
    i = 0;
    for(; s[i] && s[i] != c; i++)
        cpy[i] = s[i];
    cpy[i] = '\0';
    return cpy;
}

static void cleanup(char **cpy) {
    if(!cpy)
        return;
    for(int i = 0; cpy[i]; i++)
        free(cpy[i]);
    free(cpy);
}

char **ft_split(char const *s, char c) {
    if (!s && !c)
        return NULL;
    size_t count = ft_length(s, c);
    char **cpy = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
    if (!cpy)
        return NULL;
    size_t j = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; s[i]; ) {
        for(; s[i] == c; i++);
        if (!s[i])
            break;
        cpy[j] = ft_copy(s + i, c);
        if (!cpy[j]) {
            cleanup(cpy);
            return NULL;
        }
        j++;
        for(; s[i] != c && s[i]; i++);
    }
    cpy[j] = NULL;
    return cpy;
}

int main(void) {
    struct tests {
        char *str;
        char c;
    } tests[] = {
        {"hello!zzzzzzzz", 'z'},
        {"\t\t\t\thello!\t\t\t\t", '\t'},
        {"^^^1^^2a,^^^^3^^^^--h^^^^", '^'}
    };
    for(struct tests *t = tests; t < &tests[sizeof tests / sizeof *tests]; t++) {
        char **s = ft_split(t->str, t->c);
        if(!s)
            return 1;
        for(size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++)
            printf("%zu: %s\n", i, s[i]);
        cleanup(s);
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out 
==14199== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14199== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14199== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14199== Command: ./a.out
==14199== 
0: hello!
0: hello!
0: 1
1: 2a,
2: 3
3: --h
==14199== 
==14199== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14199==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14199==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 1,122 bytes allocated
==14199== 
==14199== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14199== 
==14199== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==14199== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Hi that works as well. It is just that in our coding school for loops are prohibited but this still works. In the meanwhile, I managed to find another soluation by changing that if statement(s[i] != from c to '\0' that fixed the code. The rest of the feedback was useful since I am pretty new at coding and will keep those in mind.